# Storing result sets of select queries into a mysql var

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm wondering if it's possible to store a result-set of a select query into a mysql variable, while using a stored procedure?

Example of a select query:

```
SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE user_id = <input_stored_proc>
```

I have multiple select queries that I'd like to run in that stored procedure and would like to store each result-set into a different variable.

What I'd like to do is, call that stored procedure from any application and be able to do something like this: (all SELECT queries require the user_id input)

```
CALL <stored_proc_name>(<user_id>)
```

And then use the variables, so I can e.g. loop through the rows of any executed select query.

Thanks.

Comment: No, not possible. Use temporary tables to store result sets.

Comment: Yes, I've read about using temporary tables, but then I'd still have to run a select query to fetch the rows from the temp table(s), right? So then the whole purpose of having the stored procedure is gone as I can simply add the original select queries in my application instead of storing the query in the database. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: That sounds rather like you might have a wrong understanding of the what the purpose of stored procedures is to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe: To have one or multiple queries in a central place, so it can be used from whatever application you have (either it'd be PHP, C#, Java, ..)